# Trouble with view for nested attributes form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Working on my first application and am a bit stuck. I'm following the revised railscast for nested attributes but my form doesn't display the fields. The below is what I have. The date and submit fields both show but the field I'm trying to make for movements (and then I'll need one for rep and weight) just doesn't show up at all. Its as though it doesn't exist when rendered.

**/views/workouts/_workout_form.html.erb** reads:

```
<%= form_for(@workout) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'common/form_errors', object: @workout %>

    <p>
        <%= date_select :workout, :workout_date %><br />

        <%= f.fields_for :exercises do |builder| %>
        <fieldset>
            <%= builder.label :movement, "Movement" %><br />
            <%= builder.text_area :movement %>
        </fieldset>
        <% end %>

    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Log It" %>
    </p>


<% end %>
```

**/views/workouts/index.html.erb** reads:

```
<%= provide(:title, 'GymLog') %>

<div id='ask'>
<h1>Post a Workout</h1>
<% if logged_in? %>
<%= render 'workout_form' %>
<% else %>
<p>Please login</p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**/models/exercise.rb** reads:

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :workout
  attr_accessible :movement, :reps, :weight
end
```

**/models/workout.rb** reads:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :exercises
  attr_accessible :workout_date, :exercises_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises
end
```

**/controllers/workout_controller.rb** reads:

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :auth, only: [:create]

  def index
    @workout = Workout.new
  end

  def address_attributes=(attributes)
  end

  def create
    @workout = current_user.workouts.build(params[:workout])
    if @workout.save
        flash[:success] = 'Workout Recorded'
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        render 'index'
    end
  end
end
```

**/controllers/exercises_controller.rb** reads:

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you build exercises for your @workout object in controller action?

Comment: @NickKugaevsky The railscast didnt really go over the controller so probably not. Editing the post to include the controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build nested objects for newly initialized one in your controller action. Try it out:

```
# controllers/workouts_controller.rb

class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController  
  # ...

  def index
    @workout = Workout.new
    @workout.exercises.build
  end

  # ...
end
```